# Java script Replace giving empty while removing decimal

Tags: javascript

I have a string with decimal number and trying  to remove decimal symbol 
   ("690.00".replace(/./g, ''));

when i run above in java script, i am getting "" as result.  My aim was to remove  "." from the string and get 69000

Comment: [`.` is a special character in `RegExp` expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions). It should be `/\./g` instead.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts. Thank you .. that was the problem  i was facing.  Special character

Comment: Look this for the solution. https://jsfiddle.net/smit_patel/yvazwdn0/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier way to do this is to use `split` with `join`:

```
mynumber = mynumber.split('.').join('');
```

Or, if you want to use `replace` with a regular expression, you will need to add a `\` character before your dot:

```
mynumber = mynumber.replace(/\./g, '');
```

Snippet for method 1:

```js
var myNumber = '690.00';
myNumber = myNumber.split('.').join('');
console.log(myNumber);
```

Snippet for method 2:

```js
var myNumber = '690.00';
myNumber = myNumber.replace(/\./g, '');
console.log(myNumber);
```

Answer (score -2):

simply use ("690.00".replace(".",""));

Comment: It will not remove all  decimal symbol.  690.00.0012 will fail

Comment: @makdu then again, `690.00.0012` isn't a valid number.

Comment: @makdu i just assume its a normal decimal character, if you want it like that then you can simply use ("690.00.0012".replace(/\./g,''));

Comment: @PatrickRoberts This is a special number getting populated from different  condtions and need to convert to a decimal